# Flask form.validate_on_submit() no longer working, what is the replacing syntax? Is it form.validate()?

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a social network site as a hobbie, and it used to work fine, but somehow Flask change and now it does not.

I am trying to make the forms validate work in flask, but when I submit the form nothing happens, which I think is because something changed within flask. For instance the error said that form does not contain validate_on_submit , however before it used to work. I solved the error by changing it to form.validate(), but it does not work as expected.  Do you have any suggestions to make this form submit like it used to ?

Here's the `app.py` file

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask import (Flask, g , render_template, flash, redirect, url_for,abort, request, make_response)
from flask_login import (LoginManager, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user)
#from flask.ext.bcrypt import check_password_hash
from flask_bcrypt import check_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import forms 
import models 
#import boto
import boto3

    

    @app.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    form= forms.RegisterForm()
    #filename='mama.jpg'
    #Filenamepath=os.path.join("./static/img/", filename)
    #print(Filenamepath)
    #if form.validate_on_submit():
    if form.validate():    
    
        UPLOAD_FOLDER= 'static'
        file= form.photo.data
        filename= secure_filename(file.filename)
       
        Key=form.username.data;
        Filenamepath=os.path.join("./static/img/", filename)
        file.save(os.path.join("./static/img/", filename))
        s3_client.upload_file(Filenamepath, BUCKET, Key, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)
        flash("Yah , you registered!", "success")
        models.User.create_user(username=form.username.data, email= form.email.data, password=form.password.data,gender=form.gender.data, age=form.age.data, aboutme=form.aboutme.data)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
        #p= make_response(render_template('register.html', form=form))
        #filename= secure_filename(file.filename)
        #print(filename)
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

This is `register.html`

```
</section>
<form method="POST" action="" class="form">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.hidden_tag }}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ render_field(field) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Login!</button>
</form>
```

And the `forms.py` file

```
from flask_wtf import Form

from flask_wtf.file import FileRequired, FileField, FileAllowed
from models import User
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, RadioField, IntegerField, FileField 
from wtforms.validators import (DataRequired, Regexp , 
Email, EqualTo, Length, ValidationError)


    class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField(
        'Username',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Regexp(
                r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$',
                message=("Username should be one word, letters, "
                         "numbers, and underscores only.")
            ),
            name_exists
        ])
    email = StringField(
        'Email',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Email(),
            email_exists
        ])
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=2),
            EqualTo('password2', message='Passwords must match')
        ])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Confirm Password',
        validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    
    gender = RadioField('Gender', choices = [('M','Male'),('F','Female')])
    age = IntegerField('Age')
    aboutme = TextAreaField('What you looking for?')
    photo = FileField('photo')    
    #photo = FileField('image', validators=[   FileRequired(),FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only!')])
```

Answer (score 0):

In `flask-wtf v0.13.x` (from 2016 or so), the package deprecated the use of `Form` and [replaced it with `FlaskForm`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/api/?highlight=FlaskForm#flask_wtf.FlaskForm), and `FlaskForm` has `validate_on_submit()` on it.

So update your import in `forms.py` to use the new name:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
# ... other ...

# Change your RegisterForm to subclass FlaskForm
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):

# ... more ...
```

And the big difference between `validate_on_submit` vs. `validate` is that the former only validates if the form was submitted via `POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE`, and it just calls `validate()` if so.

Here's the source code for `validate_on_submit` (which hasn't changed in many years):

```
In [1]: from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
In [2]: FlaskForm.validate_on_submit??
Signature: FlaskForm.validate_on_submit(self)
Source:
    def validate_on_submit(self):
        """Call :meth:`validate` only if the form is submitted.
        This is a shortcut for ``form.is_submitted() and form.validate()``.
        """
        return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
```